# changing cursor style using javascript

Tags: javascript, cursor

I am working on a browser game where I am using custom cursors.
I am setting up the custom cursor for the entire page in my CSS
(for some reason if I set it up for the 'body' sometimes it changes back to default cursor at some area)

```
html {
  cursor: url("http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/defaultcursor.png"), default;
}
```

I would like to overwrite the url property of the above CSS using javascript

For example when the user is moving the map I would like to use this custom cursor:

```
http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/movecursor.png
```

How can I change this value using javascript?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/movecursor.png"), default';`

Comment: Thanks mate, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'url("http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/movecursor.png"), default';
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you explain it, you don't even need javascript ?
Why not just do something like

```
.map:hover{ cursor : url('http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/movecursor.png') }
```

Comment: I will use a few different cursor (for moving on map, building a road, planting a tree, etc.) sorry for didn't explain it further

Comment: Ho then you want it to change on click over something I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, If you need js, otherwise follow the above css...

```
      <span onmouseover="changeCursor(this,'http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/movecursor.png');" onmouseout="changeCursor(this,' url("http://www.iwansfactory.com/tycoon/defaultcursor.png"), default');"> Hello World </span>

        function changeCursor(el, cursor)
        {   

             el.style.cursor = cursor;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want  the cursor changes to the move-cursor,  you could try the event `MouseOver` to change its style when the mouse hover on the map,and the event `MouseOut` to return to default.

Answer (score 0):

You could add css classes for each cursor type, then onmouseenter event apply your game logic to choosing which css class to apply.